# What hardware support is needed for linux to do `gettimeofday` / `clock_gettime` in userspace using `hped`?

Tags: linux-kernel, time, system-calls

On reasonably modern systems Linux can service "system" calls like `gettimeofday` and `clock_gettime` entirely in userspace through the `linux-vdso.so` (or `linux-gate.so`) virtual library, so it does not actually perform a system call. On systems that have a stable time stamp counter (tsc) that is used, but if not Linux uses the `hpet` (high precision event timer) hardware. It can still do this in userspace by mapping the hardware registers into userspace as part of `linux-vdso.so`.

I recently discovered that on one Atom N450 based netbook (running 32 bits linux) these system calls were not serviced in userspace, but I was unable to figure out which specific feature Linux needed that this netbook didn't support. Other non-time-related system calls like `getpid` were serviced entirely in userspace.

So, what specific hardware features does Linux require/check for in order to expose `hpet` timers to userspace? And how can I see if my system has those or not?